# Использование оператора RxJS ForkJoin

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Как правильно переписать данную конструкцию с оператором RxJS ForkJoin?

```js
 this.arrItems.forEach((item) => {
      this.objectService.update(item).subscribe();
 });
```

с ForkJoin:

```js
    const streams = this.arrItems.map(item =>
   this.objectService.update(item));
    forkJoin(...streams).subscribe();
          
       //objectFacade
       public update(itemObject: ItemObject): Observable<ItemObject> {
        let observable; this.objectService.update(this.map(itemObject));
        return observable
          .flatMap(objective => this.getItemObject(itemObject.id))
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
      }
      
      //objectService
        public update(item: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + item.id, item)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```

Cтреляет ошибка `Argument of type 'void[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscribableOrPromise<any>'.   Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<any>'.     Property 'then' is missing in type 'void[]'.` в `forkJoin(streams).subscribe`

Comment: А зачем именно ForkJoin? Почему не mergeMap?

Comment: `forkJoin` массив принимает, передаешь массив и `mergeMap`, делов то

Comment: ну и если ты вбьешь в гугле `forkJoin` - то наткнешься на первую ссылку с [отличными примерами](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: @overthesanity внес правки в код, не могли бы вы меня поправить?

Comment: @new_user503 `mergeMap(item => this.objectService.update(item))`, `subscribe` после `forkJoin`

Comment: @new_user503 хотя стой, я вру, после выходных лампы не прогрелись до сих пор. Тебе не нужен `mergeMap`. Тебе нужно создать массив потоков `const streams = this.arrItems.map(item => this.objectService.update(item))` и передать его в `forkJoin(streams).subscribe(...)`. Если версия rx ниже 6.4, то `forkJoin(...streams)`

Comment: @overthesanity у меня стреляет ошибка `Argument of type 'void[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscribableOrPromise<any>'.   Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<any>'.     Property 'then' is missing in type 'void[]'.` в `forkJoin(streams).subscribe`

Comment: что такое `this.objectService.update(...)` ?

Comment: @overthesanity внес правки в код